# libnl1.1-6 /netlink/genl/genl.h no such directory

Tags: wireless, hostapd

I'm trying to compile hostapd, and for that it needs the headerfile genl.h which is supposed to be a part of the libnl1 library (I searched around, the best I got was a recommendation to update libnl1.1)

Somehow that headerfile is not available on the system anywhere, I checked some include folders and used

```
locate genl.h
```

but got no result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/usr/include/netlink/genl/genl.h` header file is contained in the `libnl-dev` package.
The latest version in the repositories is 1.1-7.

`sudo apt-get install libnl-dev` will also install the libnl1 library as a dependency.